# Can I change rectangular pads on every pin to rounded rectangular?

Tags: pcb-design, routing

I am currently routing my board with FreeRouting and I noticed that rectangular and oval pads (on KiCad) make FreeRouting do 90° cuts which I simply don't like so I thought I could simply change rectangular and oval to rounded or circle.

Is that OK for things like [MOSFETs](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BUK98150-55A.pdf) which have defined rectangular shapes?

Extra question : Why does KiCad have the default footprint for THT resistors with one round and the other oval?

Comment: Multipin through-hole part footprints sometimes make pin 1 rectangular and the others rounded, so you can identify this without a silkscreen print. IMHO this is a practise from a past age and I rather make all pins round to save the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually rounded rectangular are 99% compatible with the rectangular ones, unless you have extreme filled forming issues. In fact rounded pads are better than rectangulars but they need more space to develop the same holding force.

As for the pin 1 squared is simply and inspection convention to identify the first pad when you have no silk screen. On some connector in fact you *don't* wan't the first one squared because otherwise the traces won't fit

Comment: Does that mean if I change it to rounded ones I should increase the size a bit to compensate for the holding force ?

Comment: No round pads aren’t significantly weaker than rectangular ones.  Once the copper starts to delimitate in the middle it’s pretty much game over.

Comment: In fact it's the other way, the solder fillets holds better on round surfaces (it's a mechanical thing)